# Minecraft doesn't run; I do all the things to fix it, but it doesn't works!

Tags: java, minecraft, openjdk, oracle

1. No OpenJDK 7 Java Runtime on the dialog box.
2. Done fixing this.

   [image]
3. Here's my Java version.

   [image]

*I'd just reformatted my PC because there's problems in the last Ubuntu installation but Minecraft works fine there.*

I am using TeamExtreme Minecraft Launcher.

Comment: I am having the same problem in ubuntu 14.04 lts, but minecraft is still playable if you execute the jar file from the terminal. But the openjdk 7 option is still not there in the right-click menu.

Comment: Requesting delete...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minecraft launchers often support multiple versions of java by specifying the java executable directly. Indeed, the same is true of the generic minecraft launcher. This means that just having java 1.7 installed might not be enough, you might still be running minecraft with an incompatible version.

Try checking the settings of the launcher the ensure that they point to the correct java install.

Moreover, since this is a minecraft launching problem. there is probably a way to get the console output from the launcher so you can see what error it returns when minecraft fails to start. It would help to update the question with details of the output from the launcher ans preferably the command line actually executed by the launcher - I normally add a bunch of options to improve performance so the launcher might be adding some options that are causing you trouble.

Comment: Okay... I will test it on other JARs.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```

> Once installed, run Minecraft from the menu / Dash, login with your
>   Minecraft account and the installation should start automatically.

[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/easily-install-minecraft-in-ubuntu-via.html)

... and you can play Minecraft

Comment: I am not Premium.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to add webupd8team Java PPA repository in your system. After that install, Oracle Java 8 using following a set of commands.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

After successfully installing Oracle Java using above step verify installed version using the following command.

`java -version`

java version "1.8.0_144"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the file has execute permissions: 
`chmod +x /path/to/file.jar`

or right click on the file/propierties/permissions and check the "Allow executing file as program" box

Execute via command line the jar file: `java -jar /path/to/file.jar`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `+x`?

Comment: correct, +x, sorry

Comment: Done that, nothing works.

Comment: Does it brings an error message when executing the file.jar via terminal? What it says?

Answer (score -1):

Im hoping that this answer will help at least some of you. Open the .jar file by right-clicking on it and selecting "open with Java". When just double-clicking it, it usually tries to launch the .jar file using wine.